# Make UserControl resize when Dock = Fill

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface

I have a problem with `UserControl` that I'm crafting. It consists of `TableLayoutPanel` with another `TableLayoutPanel` in it with `ListView` inside. I want to make it resizable so that it will fit in left panel of my app and behave somewhat like Toolbox in Visual Studio. The problem is that my control doesn't scale when I resize panel.

`UserControl` is embedded in panel with `Dock = Fill` and `Anchor = Tob, Left, Bottom, Right`. Also all controls in it are made that way. How can I fix this?

**EDIT:** It's WinForms, not XAML.

Comment: Can you post the relevant bit from your XAML? Edit: Oops, sorry for the ignorance :)

Comment: It's WinForms, not XAML.

Comment: The OP is using WinForms. Hence, no XAML.

Comment: The TableLayoutPanel properties matter.  You must dock or anchor it so it grows when the user control grows.  Etcetera.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for the AutoSize properties on the TableLayoutPanel and the AutoSize ColumnType of that panel.
You can achieve something like a Dock = Fill by simply auto-sizing the table layout panel (GrowAndShrink) so that it will always fit your inner control.
Please post your designer code to see how you embedded the controls in which other control.

Answer (score 0):

Use a split panel and put your `UserControl` in the left panel and `Dock.Fill` it.

Comment: It's not a solution, and `UserControl` is in a `SplitPanel` already. `PropertyGrid` in panel below resizes well, while mine doesn't.

Comment: You did not say that it was in a SplitPanel. This is the best conjecture I could make given your description. Perhaps you should elaborate and post some code?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your resize problem come from your resizing strategy of control inside the TableLayoutPanel.

The table layout panel is tricky. Regarding the resize strategy you want to follow *inside* a cell of the table panel, the control in the cell have either to be Dock.Fill or Anchor = Top, Left, Bottom, Right.

Basically:

- Il you want the grid cell to adapt to the size of the control, then have the control in the cell Anchor = Top, Left, Bottom, Right and set the row/column to autosize.
- If you want the control in the cell to adapt to the cell size, use Dock.Fill on it and use a percentage or a absolute value to size your cell.

The behavior of the TableLayoutPanel is best described in [the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms171691(v=vs.80).aspx).